# How to search grid view using registered date column using sql query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008

How to search grid view using date column?

In a SQL Server database, I have a table `Priority` with 3 columns `id`, `name` and `registered date`. For registered date, default value is `getdate()` which automatically generates the record created date and time. Now in grid view, I want to search records using this registered date.In grid view, I have dropdown search by using name and date.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SEARCHPRIOR]
    @SearchBy VARCHAR(50),
    @SearchVal VARCHAR(50),
AS
BEGIN
    IF @SearchBy = '1'
    BEGIN
        SELECT * 
        FROM PRIORITY 
        WHERE P_NAME LIKE '%' + @SearchVal + '%'
    END
    ELSE IF @SearchBy = '2'
    BEGIN
        SELECT * 
        FROM PRIORITY 
        WHERE P_TS LIKE '%' + @SearchVal + '%'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM PRIORITY 
    END
END
```

I have tried searching with this query but getting no results found in grid view. This is how table look like in SQL Server:

```
P_ID     P_NAME    P_TS
-------------------------------------------
1        High      2019-04-23 16:17:08.097
2        Medium    2019-04-24 16:17:23.070                                                               
3        Low       2019-04-25 16:17:32.420
```

This is how I call the stored procedure, with name it is searching correctly but with date, it is showing no results found.

```
public DataTable searchPRIOR(string searchBy, string searchVal)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SEARCHPRIOR", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchBy", searchBy);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchVal", searchVal);

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);

    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Please show how you are calling the SP.

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedure will not compile because of a dangling comma.

Your `WHERE` conditions cannot use an index, so there is no reason to split this across multiple queries.

You might consider writing the logic as:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[SEARCHPRIOR] (
    @SearchBy   varchar(50),
    @SearchVal  varchar(50)
) AS
BEGIN
    SELECT P.*
    FROM PRIORITY P
    WHERE (@SearchBy = '1' AND P_NAME like '%' + @SearchVal + '%') OR
          (@SearchBy = '2' AND P_TS like '%' + @SearchVal + '%') OR
          (COALESCE(@SearchBy, '') NOT IN ('1', '2'));
END;
```

I don't know if simplifying the code will fix your problem.  It is likely to be an issue in how the SP is being called, not defined.